# Consistency strength of Muller's modification of Ackermann set theory

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

In his 2001 paper [Sets, Classes and Categories](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1372/1/SetClassCat.PDF), F. A. Muller lays out a modification of Ackermann class theory that he claims is not conservative over Ackermann's original theory in the sense that it proves the consistency of $ZFC$ (he adds choice to his modification in addition to other changes), while Ackermann's theory $A$ was [equiconsistent with $ZF$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484370900112?ref=pdf_download&fr=RR-2&rr=70c04f6bc9a4c7d5) ($ZFC$ if we add choice to $A$). A brief description of the axioms of Muller's theory can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/422578/92164).

> 1. Is this claim correct?

He cites another work of his, '*Structures for Everyone. Contemplations and Proofs in the Foundations and Philosophy of Physics and Mathematics*', as the source for a proof but I don't have access to the text for proof verification. In the comments section of an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/94447/92164) to an older MO question about Ackermann's original theory the answerer contradicts Muller and claims that his theory is conservative over $ZFC$; hopefully one of the experts here can put this issue to rest for good.

If his modified theory is a step up in consistency strength from $ZFC$,

> 2. Does this remain true if we add large cardinal axioms to both theories? That is, letting $SC$ denote the theory in Muller's paper and $\mathbb{V}$ denote the universe of sets in this theory, for a large cardinal axiom $\phi$ do we have that $SC+\phi^\mathbb{V}$ is a step up in consistency strength from $ZFC+\phi$?